# Combine update and select statements containing join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have the below working select statement:

```
SELECT 
  ITEM,
  LOW,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM_STATE = 'RT' THEN QUANTO*-1 ELSE ITEMS.QUANTO END) AS QUANTO_TOTAL 
FROM ITEMS
INNER JOIN CMS 
  ON ITEMS.ORDERNO = CMS.ORDERNO
INNER JOIN STOCK 
  ON ITEMS.ITEM = STOCK.NUMBER
WHERE ODR_DATE BETWEEN '2014-03-28 00:00:00.000' 
AND '2015-03-28 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY ITEM, LOW
;
```

How do I update `STOCK.LOW` with `QUANTO_TOTAL`?

Comment: which RDBMS you are using? you have to specify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `CTE`, then join it with `STOCK`:

```
with cte as (
select ITEM,LOW,
       sum( CASE 
              WHEN ITEM_STATE = 'RT' THEN QUANTO*-1 
              ELSE ITEMS.QUANTO
            END) AS QUANTO_TOTAL 
FROM ITEMS 
INNER JOIN CMS ON ITEMS.ORDERNO = CMS.ORDERNO 
INNER JOIN STOCK ON ITEMS.ITEM = STOCK.NUMBER 
where ODR_DATE BETWEEN '2014-03-28 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-03-28 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY ITEM,LOW)
update stock
set stock.low = cte.QUANTO_TOTAL 
from cte 
join stock on cte.ITEM = STOCK.NUMBER
```